# Geolocate tweets from Twitter API - Spring social twitter

Tags: twitter, spring-social-twitter

I want to get the coordinates of tweets longitude and latitude, but I don't know how to do it. How to get coordination of data from Twitter API?

HOw do we get the geolocation using Spring social twitter ?

The `Tweet` class doesn't define a `getLocation` method.

Answer (score 0):

The geo information of a Tweet will be included when you request that specific tweet via the API, as documented here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

Comment: I want to know how to get geolocation with Spring social twitter,

Comment: In Spring you're looking for org.springframework.social.twitter.api.TweetData - which should give you more data, and a displayCoordinates method

Comment: Sorry but the getLocation returns string location , I want to know how do we get the geo coordinates of the tweet

Answer (score 0):

When you do searches for twitter with the searchOperation, it returns a org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Tweet Object which doesn't seem to have the location of the tweets.

However, the org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Tweet object has a 
org.springframework.social.twitter.api.TwitterProfile object. The TwitterProfile Object has a location field, which is the users location.